# 'No Internet Connection' on Certain Apps

Tags: chrome-for-android, internet, spotify

I'm running Android 11; in some apps, such as Chrome, I see 'No Internet Connection' at the top, but everything is fine; I can browse.
[image: No Internet Connection Chrome]

Similarly, on Spotify, I get 'No Internet Connection' and am unable to use it, but other items such as Album Cover and other information are loaded.

[image: You're Offline-Spotify]

I'm having similar issues with other apps, such as Google Keep, which won't sync properly.

I've tried reinstalling, restarting, clearing data and cache, resetting network settings.

Is there any way I can,say, view the logs and figure out the problem ?

Comment: Maybe clearing cache of apps will help? //Also, switch off mobile /Wifi data, put device in aeroplane mode fire a few seconds and switch off aeroplane mode and try. This resets wifi connection

Comment: @beeshyams Tried it. Doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're on mobile data, go to settings and locate APN (access point names) settings;  then set apn protocol and apn roaming protocol to ipv4 only from ipv4/ipv6 mode and then save it.

Comment: Still the same.